# Android URLImageViewHelper loading animation

Tags: android, image, url, gridview, load

Hi I'm using URLImageViewHelper by koush (https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper).

Loading images from URL works well, but I want to show a progress(any animation) while the images are loaded and that doesn't work. It waits for all images to be loaded and then they are displayed simultaneously. What's wrong?

PS: The hardcoded image URL is just for testing!

**My GridviewAdapter:**

```
private Context context;

public _GridAdapter(Context _context) {
    this.context = _context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return SharedVars.imageList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return SharedVars.imageList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {     
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView = null;

    if(convertview == null) {
        gridView = new View(context);
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);

        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        final ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_loading);
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(imageView, "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/" + 
                "-8HO-4vIFnlw/URquZnsFgtI/AAAAAAAAAbs/WT8jViTF7vw/s1024/Antelope%252520Hallway.jpg", new UrlImageViewCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLoaded(ImageView imageView, Bitmap loadedBitmap, String url, boolean loadedFromCache) {
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        gridView = (View) convertview;
    }

    return gridView;
}
```